# Codeigniter: Joining multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 3 tables with the following columns

```
ITEMS
-id
-name
-category_id
-brand_id

ITEM_BRAND
-id
-name

ITEM_CATEGORY
-id
-name
```

I joined them by

```
$this->db->order_by('items.name', 'ASC');
    $this->db->join('item_brand', 'item_brand.id = items.brand_id');
    $this->db->join('item_category', 'item_category.id = items.category_id');
    $query = $this->db->get("items");
```

**Question:**

Since all columns are selected, is it possible to select a column from a definite table(such as item_brand.name)?

I did the following code, yet I am getting zero results. 
but if I remove this following line,

```
$this->db->join('item_category', 'item_category.id = items.category_id');
```

and loading `$data['name']` to the view, all I get is the `brand.name`

I need to join the 3 tables. But I failed to do so.

Edit:
I managed to make a solution for the columns, however, I'm getting zero results joining the 3 tables.

```
$this->db->select('items.name, 
        items.category_id, 
        items.srp, 
        items.dp, 
        items.brand_id, 
        items.id, 
        items.serial, 
        item_brand.name AS item_brand, 
        item_category.name AS item_category');
    $this->db->order_by('items.name', 'ASC');        
    $this->db->join('item_category', 'item_category.id = items.category_id');
    $this->db->join('item_brand', 'item_brand.id = items.brand_id');
    $query = $this->db->get("items");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to select a column from a definite table(such as
>   item_brand.name)?

Yes, you can select column from definite table using `select` as below :

```
 $this->db->select('item_brand.name');
 $this->from('items');
 $this->db->join('item_brand', 'item_brand.id = ems.brand_id');
 $this->db->join('item_category', 'item_category.id = items.category_id');
  $query = $this->db->get("items");
```

And if you are not getting results while joining your `item_category` table i.e.

```
$this->db->join('item_category', 'item_category.id = items.category_id');
```

then there must be issue with the foreign key  i.e. `join` uses `inner join` of mysql which takes all intersect(common) data between the joined tables and there must be no matching `id`(foreign key) in `item_category` and `items` table. So, you can use `rightjoin` to get the data. Which will take all data from items table and all the data from `item_category` table if there is any matching foreign key (items_category.id) from `items` table. 
So, what you can do is :

```
 $this->db->select('item_brand.name');
 $this->from('items');
 $this->db->join('item_brand', 'item_brand.id = ems.brand_id');
 $this->db->join('item_category', 'item_category.id = items.category_id','right');
  $query = $this->db->get("items");
```

If you want to explore more then you can visit [this](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html) doc .

Hope it helps. Happy coding :) .

Comment: i do this same thing. but 1 problem i got. `('items')` primary key `id` is not showing. `item_category` `id` shows in array. hope you understand what i need to say. help me if you got my message. thanks.

Comment: i got solution.

`$this->db->select('*,item_brand.id as item_brand_id, item_category.id as item_category_id');`